# Jquery Get all DIV with certain pattern and add class into it

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, find

I use 3rd party tool and it's generate numbers of div as below.

```
<div style="height:auto;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c1-F1246"></div>
<div style="height:auto;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c1-F1247">1</div>
<div style="height:auto;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c1-F1248"></div>
<div style="height:auto;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c1-F1249">1</div>
```

I like to use jquery to find all the div with the class ="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-XX-XXXX" and with the content in the div =1 to change the css background color.

Note:XX-XXX can be any number which is not fixed length.

I tried with single cell but does not change the background color.

```
$('div').find('datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c1-F1249').css('background-color', 'red');
```

How can I achieve this? Anyone can help?

Comment: Could you not use the `datagrid-cell` class instead of the `datagrid-cell-XX-XXXX`?

Comment: because it's auto generate by the 3rd party tools. so i can't control it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('.parent').find('div[class^="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-"]:contains(1)').css('background', 'red');
```

or

```
$('div[class^="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-"]:contains(1)').css('background','red');
```

Comment: yes. it's change color, but i need to change all background color which has class name like this pattern class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-XX-XXX" and it's contain text = 1

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('[class^=datagrid-cell datagrid-cell]:contains("1")').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Alternatively if you can just use the `datagrid-cell` class which is on all the cells too, you can simplify to:

```
$('.datagrid-cell:contains("1")').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need wildcard selector, `starts with`. You can read more about selectors over [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Selectors&redirect=no)

```
$('[class^=datagrid-cell datagrid-cell:contains(1)]').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but I guess it was because OP needs to select elements with the class *and* also have text = '1'

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, so nice of you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not one class but a set of two classes, this should do it:

```
$('div').find('.datagrid-cell.datagrid-cell-c1-F1249').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: `Note:XX-XXX can be any number which is not fixed length.`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry, I got the question wrong, your solution should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div.datagrid-cell:contains('1')').css('background-color', 'red');
```

This will selects all div elements that have class "datagrid-cell" and contains value "1". Your elements contains two classes "datagrid-cell" and autogenerated "datagrid-cell-XX-XXXXX".

Comment: Please add more body to your question other than a line of code, a description of the contains selector should suffice, although also note that that OP has mentioned that the class for the `datagrid-cell` is autogenerated.